# Can I ask the following question

Tags: discussion, why-questions

Can I ask this short question ? is it necessary to provide details or is it enough?:

Why Russia 90% of its [attacks](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/oct/07/russia-airstrikes-syria-not-targetting-isis) are on Syria opposition? And not on ISIS especially both of them cause threat to Syria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you ask this particular question, you should reflect and think "Do I think I know the answer to this question?"  If you do, then you should probably refrain from asking the question.  Stack Exchange is for answering questions.  It is **not** a place for creating a dialog, and it is **not** your personal blog.

That being said, if you asked that question as-is, I would expect our members to answer it as though it were asked in good faith.

A couple of notes:

- Before you ask, you should make sure that your question is not a duplicate.
- You might want to rephrase it a bit to be more clear.

  > Why are 90% of the attacks Russia makes in Syria not target toward ISIS.
- Include what you need to for people to understand your question, but do your best to avoid including distracting elements to your question.  Remember, the more details you include, the more nits there will be for nitpickers to pick.
- Don't worry too much about nitpickers.  Even if more than half of Russian attacks **are** against ISIS, a person can answer your question by simply providing the correct numbers, while including a reason why you should trust their numbers over the article you linked to.

Comment: -1. Not to rant, but this answer looks like a true conclusion deduced from false premises. The yellow popup on a downvote button says, "this Q does not show any research effort", so we must attempt to answer the Q ourselves, *prior to asking*. Hence, at the moment of asking, we would find **at least several answers**. Maybe they are incomplete or otherwise unacceptable for the OP. This applies to all SE sites, but here at Politics.SE this becomes most apparent. Again, I'm talking only about the 1st paragraph of this answer.

Comment: @bytebuster your comment is rambling.  Could you more clearly explain exactly what your issue is with this answer?

Comment: My point is that prior research (a required thing before asking) makes us know answer(s) to the question. So, the suggestion *«you should reflect and think "Do I think I know the answer to this question?" If you do, then you should probably refrain from asking the question.»* only leads to badly researched questions and does not actually help from opinionated ones. Does it make sense?

Comment: @bytebuster Nothing about I said implies that a question can't have other kinds of problems(such as the kinds of problems that arise from poorly researched questions).  I merely stated that the OP should ask a genuine question instead of making a statement.  The reason I singled that particular issue out is because the OP is asking about a specific question, and that is the guideline that specific question is the most likely to run afoul of.

Comment: @bytebuster I then, went on to tell the OP to do thinggs such as `Before you ask, you should make sure that your question is not a duplicate`, and `Include what you need to for people to understand your quesiton`.  In case you didn't know, **the reason why** we "require" research is to satisfy those two points.

Comment: Yes, this is a good intent, but it is not the way how the answer is formulated. Would you consider re-wording the 1st paragraph to something like: *«…you should reflect and think: Do I genuinely ask for information or am I rather trying to deliver some information or statement, covered in a form of a question?»*

Comment: @bytebuster 1.  That answer would have an accusatory tone, and turn it's audience off.  2.  people are more likely to say "no" to your phrasing than mine, because they usually don't want to think they're doing something deceptive like that.  3.  That phrasing has nothing to do with research

Answer (score 6):

Is it strictly **necessary** to provide details? Not according to official rules.

Is it a **good idea** to provide details? Absolutely.

Personally, I would:

- Downvote the question as stated
- Upvote the exact same question if you add reasonably solid evidence for the fact you are asserting (90% figure). It doesn't have to be ironclad proof, but something that would lead me to believe that it's not just a made-up figure or a guess.

Ironically, if you don't have good evidence for your claim, you **can** avoid needing to justify your assertion, merely by not making the assertion in the first place and asking others to provide evidence for you, which would also be a good question:

> ***What is the fraction of attacks that Russia makes in Syria which targets ISIS vs. non-ISIS opposition***?